# Reading Tab delimited file in Pandas with unintended line break

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read the uncompressed version of the file found here:
http://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pub/clinvar/tab_delimited/variant_summary.txt.gz

I'm using Pandas and the read_table function; however, some lines contain the text OMIM: before the tab, which appears to be causing an unintended line break. Rows that contain a string after OMIM: do not seem to have this issue.

I assume that the : is causing it act up somehow, but not sure how to resolve it to read the rest of the row properly. It also screws up importing to Excel, so I'm confident it's something with the text.

Using Python3 and the latest version of Pandas.

Comment: the problem is that some of rows contain `'\x00'` symbol (a character with `0` ASCII code) after `OMIM:`. You can easily see it in any HEX editor, just look for hex code `00`...  So i guess you will need to preprocess  your file (remove/replace all `'\x00'` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSV file contains NULL bytes (i.e. `b'\x00'`). Although the file is somewhat big (100+MB), it is (probably) small enough to be read entirely into memory. So a quick fix would be to remove the NULL bytes with:

```
with open('variant_summary.txt', 'rb') as f, open('variant_summary-fixed.txt', 'wb') as g:
    content = f.read()
    content = content.replace(b'\x00', b'')
    g.write(content)
```

(If the file were too big to comfortably fit in memory, you would have to read
and write the file in chunks -- not terribly difficult, but more code.)

Once you have the fixed version of the data file, variant_summary-fixed.txt, you can
load it into pandas as normal:

```
df = pd.read_table('variant_summary-fixed.txt', delimiter='\t')
```